# Unit tests for React component with Hls VideoPlayer

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, http-live-streaming, ts-jest

How can i write unit tests jest/testing-library/react for this component?
I tried, but nothing works. I use React 18.1

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Hls from "hls.js";
import LockedVideoImg from "../../images/lockedVideo.png";

interface VideoPlayerProps {
  videoLink: string;
  previewImageLink: string;
  order: number;
  id: string;
  status: "locked" | "unlocked";
}

const VideoPlayer: React.FC<VideoPlayerProps> = ({
  videoLink,
  previewImageLink,
  order,
  id: videoId,
  status,
}: VideoPlayerProps) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

  const poster = `${previewImageLink}/lesson-${order}.webp`;
  const isUnlocked: boolean = status === "unlocked";

  useEffect(() => {
    const videoElement = videoRef.current;
    if (!videoElement) return;

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      const hls = new Hls();
      attachMediaToHls(hls, videoElement);
    }
  }, [videoLink, videoId]);

  const handleSavedTime = (
    videoElement: HTMLVideoElement,
    videoId: string
  ): void => {
    const savedTime = localStorage.getItem(videoId);

    if (savedTime !== null) {
      videoElement.currentTime = parseInt(savedTime);
    }
  };

  const attachMediaToHls = (hls: Hls, videoElement: HTMLVideoElement) => {
    hls.attachMedia(videoElement);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
      hls.loadSource(videoLink);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => {
        handleSavedTime(videoElement, videoId);
      });
    });
  };

  const handleTimeUpdate = (): void => {
    const currentTime = videoRef.current?.currentTime || 0;

    if (currentTime !== 0) {
      localStorage.setItem(videoId, String(currentTime));
    }
  };

  return (
    <video
      width="100%"
      ref={videoRef}
      controls
      onTimeUpdate={handleTimeUpdate}
      poster={isUnlocked ? poster : LockedVideoImg}
    />
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

I try wrote tests for this component, but only 2 tests pass, another tests not work.I have "It should display a video" and "It should display video with controls".  I need more tests for functions in this component.

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

import Video from "../src/components/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer";

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("../src/images/lockedVideo.png", () => ({
  default: "path/to/mock/image.png",
}));

describe("Describe video component", () => {
  const mockedProps = {
    id: "1",
    previewImageLink: "",
    order: 1,
  };

  const source = "https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8";
  const videoElem = (
    <Video videoLink={source} {...mockedProps} status="unlocked" />
  );

  it("It should display a video", () => {
    render(videoElem);
    const video = document.querySelector("video") as HTMLVideoElement;

    expect(video).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("It should display video with controls", () => {
    render(videoElem);
    const video = document.querySelector("video") as HTMLVideoElement;

    expect(video).toHaveAttribute("controls");
  });
});
```